# OO basics question about delegate vs inheritance vs interface

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface, delegates

Years ago i had a course about OO where a statement was made.
I forgot that statement and would like some help getting it back to memory.

It was one of the following:

1. Everything you can do with an interface can also be done with a delegate
2. Everything you can do with an interface can also be done with inheritance
3. Everything you can do with inheritance can also be done with a interface
4. Everything you can do with an inheritance can also be done with a delegate

I know its one of them and that 1 is bound to be totally invalid

Can you please shed some light on this?

Comment: Most likely they were refering to the statement `favor composition over inheritance`. In your case, that would be statement 4. Interfaces on the other hand tend to solve the `multiple inheritance` problem quite nicely and are an powerfull tool for providing test dummies in your testcases.

Comment: Most likely this is homework...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with IAbstract - delegates have nothing to do with inheritance or interfaces so I don't think any of the statements apply.

In my opinion #2 is the correct answer.  An interface provides a set of methods, properties, and events that a implementing class must contain.  You get this by default with inheritance: all of the superclass's non-private properties, methods, and events are available to the subclass.

Inheritance provides implementation details (a method body) to a subclass, whereas an interface does not; it only provides what will be available in a given class.  This is why I don't think #3 is correct.

Comment: Ok, I follow - makes sense. This is why I don't like test questions written in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

First, delegates really don't have anything to do with inheritance or interfaces - so I would rule out both 1 and 4.

Second, consider that an `interface` is one of the following:

```
abstract class SomeInterface {
/*.. do stuff ..*/ 
}
```

... or

```
interface ISomeInterface {
/*.. do stuff ..*/ 
}
```

In order to be useful, these must be inherited by a concrete class somewhere down the hierarchy. Often, when deriving a type, you will have a choice of some interface from which to derive. Although I have never heard the statement phrased in this manner, I would select #3 - if given on a multiple choice test question.

Comment: I assume they referred to `interface delegation`, not `Delegates` as used in in `.Net`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question as C# which I can respond to. But how delegates, inheritance and
interfaces are implemented may vary in crucial ways between languages, so I'm not sure how useful abstract statements about OO are.

"A problem that can be solved with a delegate can also be solved with an an interface." -C# 4.0 In a NutShell

[MSDN programming guide interface vs delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173173.aspxhttp://)

You can certainly do everything you can with inheritance via interfaces, but it can lead to a lot of redundant code. Hence there is no good substitute for multiple inheritance when its really needed which C# lacks.

Anything you can do in a high level language you can do in assembler, but that may not be practically useful if you are concerned with productivity.